# Dataframes in dictionary merged with another df

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, merge

I'm reading in multiple sheets from an excel file and trying to perform some cleanup. Since the number of sheets and columns can vary from file to file, loading into a dictionary seems to be most practical.

The problem that I am encountering is when I want to perform a merge between each dictionary df and a third_party_df it is not performing the merge. I assume this is due to the fact that the variable df in a loop is behaving differently then what I would expect.

```
import pandas as pd
dict_dfs = pd.read_excel('test_file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
third_party_df = pd.read_excel('another_file.xlsx')

for key,df in dict_dfs.items():
    df.dropna(axis='columns', how='all', inplace=True)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
    df = pd.merge(df, third_party_df, how='left', on='merge_column')
```

I tried also an option to assign to a key df but that resulted in an error instead:

```
df[key] = pd.merge(df, third_party_df, how='left', on='merge_column')
```

Comment: `df[key]` - did you mean `dict_dfs[key]`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the original dictionary, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'match': [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [1,2,3], 'match': [3,2,1]})
df_dict = {'df1': df1, 'df2': df2}
for key, df in df_dict.items():
    df_dict[key] = pd.merge(df, df2, how = 'left', on = 'match')
```